# Mysql -uroot -pxxx hanging

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql slave installed on a Centos machine.
Suddenly I can't login anymore in to the slave from the local machine:

```
mysql -uroot -p
Enter password:........(After entering password no answer)
```

Mysqld is running, CPU and memory usage are normal. Mysqladmin commands like status, processlist etc, also freeze.
Nothing strange in the logs, lot of memory free on disk.
I see "some" activity in the slave logs, but I'm not sure if it's really replicating or not.

Before killing brutally the slave and restarting, there is something else I could try?
thanks

Comment: Did you install another MySQL service? Are you running the code from PutTy?

Comment: whats the output of `SHOW PROCESSLIST`? maybe you reached the max number of connections ?

Comment: I'm on the machine itself via ssh.

Comment: if you mean mysqladmin -uroot -p processlist, it hangs!!!

Comment: and no, there isn't any other mysql service installed

Comment: @Stephan, ok, SHOW PROCESSLIST \G; from master doesn't show any Command: Binlog dump...so...is the slave dead?

Comment: hmmm... run `SHOW SLAVE STATUS` on slave server and look at the `Seconds_Behind_Master` column is the value is big i assume this is the problem : the slave is struggle-ling to catch the master server

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ok,  centos box was out of memory...!!

Comment: This actually does answer the question: RAM being exhausted and the machine going into swap is the reason for the hanging, and the ONLY way to get the database back, if issuing regular stops don't work (they kept timing out for me), is to issue a 'killall -9 mysqld', and cross all your fingers and toes that you don't cause data corruption and/or that your backups are good.